# Get text from dynamic select option

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have more than one select option, i want to write text `car` or `motorcycle` on `.texts`

This a few dynamic select option

```
<td>

<select id="area-0">
  <option value="1">Car</option>
  <option value="2">Motorcycle</option>
</select>
</td>

<td class="texts"></td>

<td>
    <select id="area-1">
      <option value="1">Car</option>
      <option value="2">Motorcycle</option>
    </select>
</td>

<td class="texts"></td>
```

this my script

```
$('select[id^=area]').change(function(){
    var text_t = $(this option:selected).text();
  $(this).parent().next().html(text_t);

});
```

How can i place `car` or `motorcycle` on `.texts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.find()` method to get the selected `option`'s text. As per current implementation you must be getting syntax error.

```
var text_t = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

instead of

```
var text_t = $(this option:selected).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

> You have invalid `html`. Wrap it in `table -> tr`
>
> `$(this option:selected)` is not a valid selector. Use `$(this).find('option:selected')`

```js
$('select[id^=area]').change(function() {
  var text_t = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  $(this).parent().next().html(text_t);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="area-0">
        <option value="1">Car</option>
        <option value="2">Motorcycle</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="texts"></td>
    <td>
      <select id="area-1">
        <option value="1">Car</option>
        <option value="2">Motorcycle</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="texts"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```